# React navigates instead of opening pdf

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Let's say I'm on livepage.hu and:
On my live page I have this code: 
`<a href="https://livepage.hu/myDocument.pdf">Click Me!</a>`

On click it navigates to the URL and shows a blank page since there's no such route in my react router v4

`<a href="https://livepage.hu/myDocument.pdf" download>Click Me!</a>` 
Works as expected, it will download the document on click

In localhost: 
`<a href="http://localhost:3000/myDocument.pdf">Click Me!</a>` 
Will open the pdf in the browser which is the desired on the live page also.

`target="_blank"` or other options for this attribute won't help

Comment: `it navigates to the URL and shows a blank page since there's no such route in my react router v4` navigates where? you want to say that it navigates to `https://livepage.hu/myDocument.pdf` and renders blank page? then it's has nothing to do with react router.

Comment: Are you using `<a>` or `<Link>` tag in your JSX ?

Comment: @dfsq yes, that's what I mean! But on localhost it's working fine. The reason for rme thinking it's the router is that the `https://livepage.hu/myDocument.pdf` pages have the header and side bars only the content is 'missing'
@Dyo I'm using `<a> ` tag. Actually that HTML comes from the API.